# Trigger change on selecting dataset [Amcharts Multiple Data Sets chart]

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

is it possible to trigger a 'change' on the select element of the amcharts multiple data set chart that they have provided.?

```
$(".amChartsDataSetSelector").find("select").val("2").trigger("change");
```

This is the code i tried,what it does basically is **change the select option to the one i have selected** ,but it **doesn't change the chart accordingly**.

Is there any **other alternatives** to this method?

**Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9vpxzbq/1/):**

**Here's the [original link](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/#) to the chart on amcharts.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The jQuery `.trigger(` works only when events are bound using jQuery `.on` function (or any event binding function).](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/#how-can-i-mimic-a-native-browser-event-if-not-trigger) Below is a simple example to show you what was happening.

Jump to #Solution below to skip this demo.

```js
$(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('checkEvent');
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener("change", checkEvent, false);
  } else {
    el.attachEvent('change', checkEvent);
  }

  function checkEvent() {
    alert('Event Check');
  }

  $('#changeDDValue').click(function() {
    $('#checkEvent').val("2").change();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="checkEvent" style="width: 180px;">
  <option value="0">first data set</option>
  <option value="1">second data set</option>
  <option value="2">third data set</option>
  <option value="3">fourth data set</option>
</select>
<button id="changeDDValue">Change DataSet</button>
```

### Solution:

Added a button `#change` to set a different dataset like below,

```
$('#change').click(function () {
    var selectEl = $(".amChartsDataSetSelector").find("select").val("2").get(0);
    fireEvent.call(selectEl, 'change');
});
```

And then use fireEvent function below to trigger the change event instead of `trigger('change')`,

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/297641
function fireEvent(eventName) {
    var event; // The custom event that will be created

    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
    }

    event.eventName = eventName;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        this.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
    }
}
```

[**Fixed jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dejfjxc/)

Comment: Works perfect. 
But can you please add a description to what the fireEvent function does? 
Thanks

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Glad it worked for you. fireEvent is just a function to trigger an event bound using native API (addEventListener/attachEvent). Check the SO link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/297641 just above the function for more information.

Comment: I will implement this onto ma project,and will accept you ans.