# AmCharts Stock Chart: remove Compare to selection box

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dejfjxc/) used in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562276/trigger-change-on-selecting-dataset-amcharts-multiple-data-sets-chart).

Everything works, however I can't find a way to remove the selection box underneath the "Compare to:" label, as indicated in the red box the picture.

[image]

Is there a way to hide or deactivate it?

I tried the following `dataSetSelector` settings but this only removed the "Compare to" text, not the selection box underneath:

```
dataSetSelector: {
    selectText :"",
    compareText: "",
    comboBoxSelectText : "",
    position: "top"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the compare selection using CSS:

```
/* hide the compare box */
.amcharts-compare-div {
  display: none;
}

/* 
  hide all <br> tags after the dropdown,
  if dataSetSelector position is set to top or bottom, 
  hide the select due to different markup
*/
.amcharts-data-set-select ~ br, .amcharts-data-set-select ~ select {
  display: none;
}

/* add a margin-bottom to space out the dropdown from the from/to text boxes */
.amcharts-data-set-select {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

You'll still need to set `compareText` to an empty string in the `dataSetSelector` to remove the `Compare to:` string.

Demo: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e6cb53e53222eba93e80cf7e0be98987

You can find information on the class names set by AmCharts here: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/css-class-names/

Updated to also handle when the dataSetSelector's position is set to "top" or "bottom" due to different markup.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! the issue is i've changed from left to top : dataSetSelector: { position: "top" } and do not work for this position. Why ?

Comment: Interesting. Seems like the chart is generating different markup for position top and bottom. I've updated my answer's demo and CSS. You need to add `.amcharts-data-set-select ~ select` to the rule that hides the <br> tags.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot, it works :) i've additional question and I apologize. Is it possible to associate another action while changing the chart ? (example hide a div). I tried something like, but don't work : , $(function () {
    $(".amcharts-data-set-select").change(function(){
  $("#div").hide(200);
    });
});
Thanks again.

Comment: Use the [dataSetSelected](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSetSelector#dataSetSelected) event. [Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/2788581ec2cc7b5a0543c3f59000b2db?editors=0010)

Comment: It Works ! Thanks :) !